# How to install pppoe package from usb instead of cdrom?

Tags: debian, usb, repository

My debian was installed from a usb disk--/dev/sdb.
It is simple to install pppoe package from cd.

```
sudo vi  /etc/apt/sources.list 
deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 9.2.0 lxde 2017-10-07T13:15]/ stretch main
sudo apt-get install  pppoe
```

No cdrom, it is usb in my pc.
I want to install  pppoe packages from usb disk.

```
sudo  mount  /dev/sdb   /home/back
ls  /home/back/
boot  d-i  dists  isolinux  live  pool
```

To assign usb disk as source.

```
sduo vi  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb file:/home/back/ stretch main contirb
```

To install with the usb disk.

```
sudo apt-get install  pppoe
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ebtables ipset libipset3 python3-decorator python3-selinux python3-slip python3-slip-dbus
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ppp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppp pppoe
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 424 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,182 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 ppp amd64 2.4.7-1+4
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 pppoe amd64 3.12-1.1
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/ppp/ppp_2.4.7-1+4_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rp-pppoe/pppoe_3.12-1.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `pppoe` isn't included on the *Debian Live 9.2.0 lxde.iso* , you can check the list of package from here: [debian-live-9.2.0-amd64-lxde.packages](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-9.2.0-amd64-lxde.packages)

You can use the command line to check the `pppoe` package:

```
curl https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-9.2.0-amd64-lxde.packages | grep pppoe
```